# Storing input from TextFields and ComboBox in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I'm making a basic Movie Rental simulator application, and I am currently having a problem storing the input from my TextFields and my ComboBox into variables. I managed to convert most of my variables to Strings, however when I try and print the output to test it, it always returns "null."

I need to essentially figure out how to GET the selection the user has made in the combo box and store it as a string, and I need to figure out how to properly store the results from my methods. I have never ran into this problem before, so I am not really sure how to tackle it. My code is as follows:

`public class RentGameDialogController extends RentalStoreGUIController` `implements Initializable{`

```
/** TextField Objects **/
@FXML private TextField nameField, rentedOnField, dueBackField;

/** String for NameField **/
String name, rentedOn, dueBack;

/** Game ComboBox ID's **/
@FXML private ObservableList<GameType> cbGameOptions;
@FXML private ComboBox<GameType> cbGame;

/** Console ComboBox ID's **/
@FXML private ObservableList<PlayerType> cbConsoleOptions;
@FXML private ComboBox<PlayerType> cbConsole;

/** GameType object **/
private GameType game;

/** PlayerType Object **/
private PlayerType console;

/** Button ID's **/
@FXML Button cancel, addToCart;

/** Counter for calculating total **/
int gameCounter;

/** Stage for closing GUI **/
private Stage currentStage;




@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    /** Select Console **/
    cbConsoleOptions = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (PlayerType p : PlayerType.values()) { cbConsoleOptions.addAll(p); }
    cbConsole.getItems().addAll(cbConsoleOptions);

    /** Select Game **/
    cbGameOptions = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (GameType g : GameType.values()){ cbGameOptions.addAll(g); }
    cbGame.getItems().addAll(cbGameOptions);

}

public String getName(){
    name = nameField.getText();

    try {

        String[] firstLast = name.split(" ");
        String firstName = firstLast[0];
        String lastName = firstLast[1];

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return name;
}

public void getGame() {
    GameType gameChoice = cbGame.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
}

public void getConsole() {
    PlayerType player = cbConsole.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
}

public String getRentedOn() throws ParseException {

    rentedOn = rentedOnField.getText();


    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date rentedOnDate = format.parse(rentedOn);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setLenient(false);
    cal.setTime(rentedOnDate);

    try {

        cal.getTime();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return rentedOn;

}

public String getDueBack() throws ParseException {

    dueBack = dueBackField.getText();


    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dueBackDate = format.parse(dueBack);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setLenient(false);
    cal.setTime(dueBackDate);

    try {

        cal.getTime();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return dueBack;

}

/*************************************
 * This is the method to call the other
 * String methods so their output can be
 * put into my main GUI
 *
 * Current problem: game.toString() and console.toString() throw an InvocationTargetException
 * @return
 * @throws ParseException
 *************************************/

public String storePurchaseData() throws ParseException {
    gameCounter++;                    //Problem               //Problem
    String toList = getName() + " " + game.toString() + " " + console.toString() + " " +
            getRentedOn() + " " + getDueBack();

    return toList; //Returns "null null null"
}


@FXML
public void handleCancelButtonAction (ActionEvent event) {
    currentStage = (Stage) cancel.getScene().getWindow();
    currentStage.close();
}

@FXML
public void addToCartButton (ActionEvent event) throws ParseException {
    System.out.println(storePurchaseData());
    currentStage = (Stage) cancel.getScene().getWindow();
    currentStage.close();
}}
```

Enum Classes for GameType and PlayerType(Console selection):

```
public enum PlayerType {
Xbox360("Xbox 360"),
PS4("Playstation 4"),
XBoxOne("Xbox One"),
WiiU("Wii - U"),
PS3("Playstation 3"),
Wii("Nintendo Wii");

private String console;

PlayerType(String console) { this.console = console; }

public String PlayerType() { return console; }

@Override public String toString() { return console; }}
```

GameType:

```
public enum GameType {
THE_WITCHER("The Witcher 3"),
CALL_OF_DUTY_AW("Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare"),
CALL_DUTY_BLOP3("Call of Duty: Black Ops 3"),
CALL_OF_DUTY_IW("Call of Duty: Infinite Warfare"),
THE_ELDER_SCROLLS("The Elder Scrolls IV: Skyrim");

private String game;

GameType(String game) {
    this.game = game;
}

public String GameType() { return game; }

@Override public String toString() { return game; }}
```

[image: GUI Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

The only method that will return the selected value is `getName()`

The rest of the methods you are using don't return anything

```
public void getGame()  //Void return type
{
    GameType gameChoice = cbGame.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
}
```

All this does is create a `GameType` object that is accessible only inside of that method.

Instead it should be

```
public GameType getGame() //Instead of void, the type you are trying to get
{
    return cbGame.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
}
```

That way, you can then access the result by

```
GameType selectedGame = getGame();
```

If you want it as a `String` use

```
public String getGame()
{
    return cbGame.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
}
```

Comment: Would you know how to convert it to a String? I have a string value in place, but if I am returning it as type GameType, then it obviously won't work correctly.

Comment: @JarredParr, See updated answer. Otherwise, you have a `toString()` method implemented in your `GameType` enum...